# Use Reflection to find the class that a method belongs to

Tags: php, class, magento, reflection

I'm working in Magento, but this is more of a general PHP question. The situation is that within Magento, there are classes that extend classes that extend classes that extend classes. I want to be able to quickly find which class actually contains the definition for a method and/or if that method is actually [magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

So for instance, if I'm 10 levels deep into classes extending others, and 4 of those 10 classes have a method called `getHtml`, I want to be able to find out which one of those methods is actually being called when I call `$this->getHtml()`. I would also like to be able to tell if `getHtml` is actually a magic method.

How can I do this with the PHP Reflection Class, or any other programmatic means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(untested code below — if you find any bugs I'd appreciate an update in the comments)

The best you'll be able to do with the Reflection API is find the classes in the hierarchy where the method is **not** defined.  The `ReflectionClass`'s `hasMethod` feature will take parent classes into account — a better name for it might be `aClassInTheHierarchyHasThisMethod`.  Consider this (quick top-my-head) inline function

```
    $getClassesWithMethod = function($classOrObject, $method, $return=false) use(&$getClassesWithMethod)
    {
        $return = $return ? $return : new ArrayObject;
        $r = new ReflectionClass($classOrObject);
        if($r->hasMethod($method))
        {
            $return['has ' . $method . ' method'][] = $r->getName();
        }
        else
        {
            $return['no '. $method . ' method'][] = $r->getName();
        }

        $parent = $r->getParentClass();
        if($parent)
        {
            $getClassesWithMethod($parent->getName(), $method, $return);
        }
        return $return;
    };

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

    $classesWithMethod = $getClassesWithMethod($product, 'load');
    var_dump((array)$classesWithMethod);
```

Run the above, and you'll get

```
array (size=2)
  'has load method' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' (length=26)
      1 => string 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract' (length=27)
      2 => string 'Mage_Core_Model_Abstract' (length=24)
  'no load method' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Varien_Object' (length=13)
```

So you know `Varien_Object` doesn't have the method `load` defined, which means it shows up first in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.  However, you won't know if there's also a definition in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.  The Reflection API won't get you this.

What **can** get you this using the `token_get_all` method.  This method can break a PHP file down into it's component PHP/Zend tokens.  Once you have that, you can write a small parser in PHP that identifies method/function definitions in a specific class file.  You can use this to recursively check the hierarchy.  Again, an inline function.

```
    $getClassesWithConcreteDefinition = function($classOrObject,$method,$return=false) use(&$getClassesWithConcreteDefinition)
    {
        $return = $return ? $return : new ArrayObject;
        $r = new ReflectionClass($classOrObject);
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($r->getFilename()));

        $is_function_context = false;
        foreach($tokens as $token)
        {
            if(!is_array($token)){continue;}                
            $token['name'] = token_name($token[0]);
            if($token['name'] == 'T_WHITESPACE'){ continue; }

            if($token['name'] == 'T_FUNCTION')
            { 
                $is_function_context = true;
                continue;
            }

            if($is_function_context)
            {
                if($token[1] == $method)
                {
                    $return[] = $r->getName();
                }
                $is_function_context = false;
                continue;
            }
        }

        $parent = $r->getParentClass();
        if($parent)
        {
            $getClassesWithConcreteDefinition($parent->getName(),$method,$return);
        }

        return $return;
    };

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');        

    $hasActualDefinition = $getClassesWithConcreteDefinition($product, 'setData');
    var_dump((array)$hasActualDefinition);
```

Here we're checking for the `setData` method.  The above will return

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract' (length=27)
  1 => string 'Varien_Object' (length=13)
```

Because `setData` is defined in both the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` class and the `Varien_Object` class.  You should be able to modify these functions to fit your own needs.  Good luck!

Comment: Alan, I find myself on your website all of the time! It's cool to get your direct help here as well. I'll test this as soon as I'm able and get back to you.

Comment: the other programmatic means

 `grep ' load(' app -rsn`

Comment: @AntonS A good start, but there's over 200 classes with a `load` method.  How does @TylerV know which ones related to the hierarchy he's working with?

Comment: he can start by specifying or narrowing the grep path. grep is not golden in every case and gives better results with more specific method names. this is a lighter alternative for example to find out if you need more advanced logging to find out the things you are after

Comment: I eventually turned this into a helper class in a simple debug module. Working great! Thanks @AlanStorm

Answer (score 1):

> 4 of those 10 classes have a method called `getHtml`, I want to be able to find out which one of those methods is actually being called when I call `$this->getHtml()`.

The method you're probably looking for is [`ReflectionClass::getMethods()`](http://php.net/reflectionclass.getmethods) which tells method-names and their resp. classname already.

If you can't find the concrete method-name, you need to look for `__class`.

The following is an example function that does this for *public* methods:

```
function traverseParentsForMethod($objOrClassname, $methodName) {
     $refl = new ReflectionClass($objOrClassname);

     $methods = $refl->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
     foreach ($methods as $method) {
         if ($method->getName() === $methodName) {
             return $method;
         }
     }

     if ($methodName === '__call') {
         return null;
     }

     return traverseParentsForMethod($objOrClassname, '__call');
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/132292